# Querying for output address using regex and tx time range

Tags: mongodb, bitcoin, bitdb

`qqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqu08dsyxz98whc` is one out of possibly many tx which have `whc` substring in output address,

https://blockchair.com/bitcoin-cash/transaction/ce4b6388c3b57dc188bfafde87d7af28ee3ba210d0a3223a3bc86f6083337459

I would like to find such outputs for `2018-08` using bitdb query lang similar to mongodb,

```
{
  "v": 3,
  "q": {
    "find": {
      "out.e.a": { "$regex": "whc$" },
      "blk.t": {
        "$gte": "2018-08-01T00:00:00Z",
        "$lte": "2018-08-31T00:00:00Z"
      }
    },
    "limit": 1
  }
}
```

Unfortunately I'm not getting any result for such [query](https://bitdb.network/v3/explorer/ewogICJ2IjogMywKICAicSI6IHsKICAgICJmaW5kIjogewogICAgICAib3V0LmUuYSI6IHsgIiRyZWdleCI6ICJ3aGMkIiB9LAogICAgICAiYmxrLnQiOiB7CiAgICAgICAgIiRndGUiOiAiMjAxOC0wOC0wMVQwMDowMDowMFoiLAogICAgICAgICIkbHRlIjogIjIwMTgtMDgtMzFUMDA6MDA6MDBaIgogICAgICB9CiAgICB9LAogICAgImxpbWl0IjogMQogIH0KfQ==)
Is there some syntax issue which prevents correct results?

Comment: This seems `bitdb` specific ( noting that you just created the tag for this question ). I suspect at a glance though that the "dates" might be the issue here, and I don't see any example in the documentation showing date based queries. Possibly related to BSON Dates vs "strings", so showing a sample document ( or truncated to the relevant fields and data at least ) would actually gain you a wider audience

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to query using Unix timestamps instead of ISO Dates.
To convert from ISO Date to unix timestamp in javascript you can do:

```
var myDate = new Date(ISODate("2015-10-25T00:00:00.000Z"));
var myTimeStamp = myDate.getTime() / 1000;
```